# angular 4 md input container

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using dynamics form with angular(https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) but how convert this example with md-input-container and angular material?

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
<div [ngSwitch]="question.ControlType">

  <input placeholder={{question.Label}} *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.Key" [id]="question.Key">

  <select [id]="question.Key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.Key">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of question.Options" [value]="opt.OptionKey">{{opt.OptionValue}}</option>
  </select>

  <input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" [type]="question.ControlType" [formControlName]="question.Key" [(ngModel)]="question.Value" (change)="question.Value = ckb.checked" #ckb>

</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include that code - don't post it as a comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is just replacing html codes with angular material components. Angular material components have support for form controls. For example;

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
     <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
          // You can use components by wrapping with `ng-template`
          <ng-template *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'">
               <md-input-container>
                    <input mdInput placeholder="{{question.label}}" [formControl]="yourFormControlName">
               </md-input-container>
          </ng-template>
          // Or like this
          <md-checkbox *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
               {{question.label}}
          </md-checkbox>
          //...
     </div>
</div>
```

[This](https://material.angular.io/categories/forms) section has lots of examples about usage, you can combine them with dynamic forms easily.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you this is final solution:

```
<md-input-container *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'">
```